# Has NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest completion block always run on Main Thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

It seems to me like something changes with iOS8.4 maybe. The completion block to my `NSURLSession` `dataTaskWithRequest` is running on the main thread rather than the thread executing the resume. Is this new and/or correct behavior?

There are many postings like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20052746/4305146) where users want to get the completion code on the main thread, but I now find it is there already (breaking my code). Here is an isolated sample:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
        self.threadTest()
    }
    return true
}

func threadTest() {
    println("threadTest on Main Thread: \(NSThread.currentThread().isMainThread)")
    let urlString = "http://www.apple.com/contact/"
    let url = NSURL(string:urlString)
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    var configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    var session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate:nil, delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        else {
            if let result = NSString(data: data, encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding)                    {
                let partial = result.substringToIndex(10)
                println("Retrieved Page: \(partial)...")
                println("NSURLSession.dataTashWithRequest completion block on Main Thread: \(NSThread.currentThread().isMainThread)")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

With results:

> threadTest on Main Thread: false
>   Retrieved Page: `<!DOCTYPE ...`
>   NSURLSession.dataTashWithRequest completion block on Main Thread: true

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just figured out the answer. The thread of the completion handler is setup in the init of the NSURLSession.

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSession/sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:):

`init(configuration configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration, delegate delegate: NSURLSessionDelegate?, delegateQueue queue: NSOperationQueue?)`

*queue - A queue for scheduling the delegate calls and completion handlers. If nil, the session creates a serial operation queue for performing all delegate method calls and completion handler calls.*

My code that setup for completion on main thread:

```
var session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate:nil, delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
```